# What is an efficient way of back-tracking in greedy best search algorithm?

Tags: c++

I coded a greedy search algorithm , but it goes to an infinite loop as its not able to back - track , and reach the final state . How can a back-tracking be done in C++ in the most optimal way !

```
    while(!f1.eof() )
        {
            f1>>temp1>>time;

            A[i].loc_name=temp1;
            A[i].time_taken=time;

                initial_start=1; // make initial to 1 and final to i

                final_finish=i;

        i=i+1;
        }

    while(!f2.eof())
        {
            f2>>temp1>>temp2>>time;
            int ci=0;
            while( ci != i )
                {

                    if (temp1 == A[ci].loc_name)
                        {
                            flag1=ci;
                            tf1=time;

                        }
                    if (temp2 == A[ci].loc_name)
                        {
                            flag2=ci;
                            tf2=time;
                        }
                    ci=ci+1;
                }



            A[flag1].loc.push_back(flag2);
            A[flag1].time_live.push_back(time);

            A[flag2].loc.push_back(flag1);
            A[flag2].time_live.push_back(time);         

        }


//Greedy Search algorithm   
                int min,min_time,finish,start,l;
                vector<int>path;
                min_time=99999;
                l=0;
                finish=1;
                start=0;
//Choosing the node with the minimum value 
            while(finish != final_finish)
                {

                for(int u=0;u<A[start].loc.size();u++)
                    {
                        l=A[start].loc[u];
                        if(A[l].time_taken < min_time)
                            {   
                                min_time=A[l].time_taken;
                                finish = l;

                            }

                    }
                min=min+min_time;
                path.push_back(start);
                    start=finish;   
//Printing the path found by Greedy search into an output file
            f3<<A[l].loc_name<<min<<endl;
                }
```

Comment: Good job. Withdrew my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int algo(int value, int stopValue, list<int> & answer)
{
    if(value == stopValue)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(value > stopValue)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if(algo(value+2, stopValue) == 0)
    {
        answer.push_back(2);
        return 0;
    }
    if(algo(value+1, stopValue) == 0)
    {
        answer.push_back(1);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here's a trivial greedy recursive algorithm that finds the number of 2s and 1s a number is composed of. Greedy algorithms are only good for some problems and produce suboptimal results in most.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `!stream.eof()`.

```
while (!f1.eof()) {
  f1 >> temp1 >> time;

// instead becomes:
while (f1 >> temp1 >> time) {
```

The eof method checks if the last extraction tried to read past eof.  If it is set, it doesn't mean the last extraction failed either (that's the fail method).  It cannot predict the future and tell you what will happen next with the stream.  Almost the only reasonable use eof is *after* you know the stream has failed and you want to see if it failed due to eof.

```
if (stream >> var) {
  // use var
}
else { // extraction failed
  if (stream.eof()) {
    // we know why it failed
  }
  else {
    // some other reason, probably formatting
  }
}
```

I did not check the rest of your code.